# How to compare two formula (calculated) cells in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, boolean, boolean-logic, nested-if

I am trying to compare two formula (calculated) cells in Google Sheets but I am getting: `Error - Formula parse error`.

The two cells are:

- `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(E5), ISBLANK(H5)),"", E5-H5)`
- `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(E5), ISBLANK(J5)),"", E5-J5)`

And the cell I am trying to compare them in is:

- `=IF(K5==K4, "yes", "no")`

An help on how to compare these cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use just one = sign:

```
=IF(K5=K4, "yes", "no")
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested your scenario and found out that if you have values on E5 and H5, then it works as long as it is numeric. Do something like

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(E5), ISNUMBER(J5)), E5-J5, "")
```

So, if both cells are numbers, we subtract them, otherwise we have an empty value.